# React-Native after DataSource update empty screen

Tags: listview, datasource, react-native

I have a ListView with some elements, and a button that hides some elements of the list when pressed.

When I click the button, the DataSource is updated with the reduced element's set, and, if on the device I'm on the bottom of the list, an empty screen is displayed, until I perform a manual scroll.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Bests

Comment: Could you share some code ?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I used this code to bring up the list every time the button is clicked:

```
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    this.listView.scrollTo({y:0, animated: false});
});
```

Hope to help someone else.

Comment: did you add that to your _handleButtonClick() function?